# How does xgboost perform the split finding of all leaves collectively?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

In the xgboost [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf), in Section 4.1, they state that:

> In the exact greedy algorithm, we store the entire dataset in a single
> block and run the split search algorithm by linearly scanning over the
> pre-sorted entries. We do the split finding of all leaves
> collectively, so one scan over the block will collect the statistics
> of the split candidates in all leaf branches.

I don't understand how the split finding of all leaves can be done collectively and what does it actually mean? They unfortunaley do not reference any source or go into detail.

My understanding of how to find the best split (node wise), is that for each node, the loss reduction is computed for all possbile splits, for all possible features.